# Unable to uninstall ros-indigo before re-intall from the beginning

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,

I'm a newbie and have an Ubuntu 14.04 computer with ROS indigo loaded on it. I was trying to install ros-indigo-navigation, where I encountered dependency issues. I tried various suggestions and nothing worked. So, I decided to uninstall ROS and reinstall the full desktop version from the beginning. I am having trouble even uninstalling ROS.

for sudo apt-get remove ros-* or for sudo apt-get purge ros-* I get the error saying that Unable to locate package ros-apt.txt and couldn't find any package by regex 'ros-apt.txt'

I did find a file by that name in my home directory though. Any suggestions on how to overcome this and help me reinstall ROS-indigo is very much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316091/unable-to-uninstall-ros-indigo-before-re-intall-from-the-beginning/) by [kkulkarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40101/kkulkarn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The shell will expand `*` as a file wildcard, so it doesn't get passed to apt.

If you don't want the shell to do any file expansions, use single quotes around the arguments you don't want expanded:

```
sudo apt-get remove '^ros-*'
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kkulkarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40101/kkulkarn/) on 2019-02-19**:
Brilliant. I don't know why I didn't think of this even though I'm from the UNIX world! Thanks, it worked.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-02-19**:
You may want to use `'^ros-*'` to make sure that you only uninstall things starting with ros. I'm not 100% sure about this but I've seen it recommended on this site before